# Opening .py files after the 3.3.5 update

Tags: python, windows, python-3.3

I recently upgraded my Python version to 3.3.5 with much excitement, but after trying to change the default 'open with' program to the new Python IDLE, I got lost.

I tried un-installing Python 3.3.2 in hope of causing less confusion, but I still can't tell what I need to open .py files with!

I can run the programs, I set the default 'open with' program to C:\Python335\pyhton.exe but in doing that I lose my right click menu "Edit in IDLE" option, and also right clicking on my Python 3.3.5 shortcut and clicking on recent items does not open anything.

[image]

Clicking any of these files did nothing. Prior to me messing around, it would have opened the file in IDLE

[image]

Opening it still does the same thing, running the program in the cmd, but I lack the right click edit function.

What is the default 'open with' program for .py files? Also 3.3.5 still has the right click edit function right?

**Edit:**
This is what it looks like currently:

[image]

What should it say instead? Or is this what it is meant to say?

Comment: Please don't use an external Google Docs page to add images; just *link* images directly from here and anyone with enough privileges usually will inline them for you.

Comment: I would have although before I asked this question I did not have enough reputation to. Thanks though I'll remember that for future use.

Comment: Try re-installing Python, and make sure that you check the box "Register extensions" on the options screen during install.

Comment: Just un-installed it because it did not give me an option to re-install, also no register extensions option came up. Should installing it 'fresh' do the trick?

Comment: I've posted a screenshot to show you where that option is. Hope this solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you activate the "Register Extensions" option when installing Python. The options screen looks like this:

[image: Python installer screenshot]

Comment: Is it activated by default? I saw that but thought it was already on.

Comment: @FaceySmile: If it's white, then it's activated.

Comment: Thanks. I will try complete reinstall and check that box

Comment: Ugh, still in the same place as before, no right click edit and problems are as described. Made sure to enable everything, even the 'Add python.exe to Path' (If that what it's called) setting.

Comment: Hm, sorry about that. Maybe the folks over at superuser.com have a better idea. For example, there's a question that addresses your problem - one of the solutions might work for you: http://superuser.com/questions/280636/trying-to-edit-a-python-file-but-the-edit-with-idle-has-disappeared-when-i-rig

Comment: Thanks! Problem is fixed and I now have the edit with IDLE button back in the right click menu. I followed what that link had about the registery editing.